# Why does Grails' cookieService.get always return null?

Tags: grails, cookies, groovy

This line

```
def cookieService
def cookieContent = cookieService.get("cookieName")
```

returns `null`, although the cookie is set correctly. I try to get content from other cookies too, but it just returns `null`. Does somebody have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Setting the cookie like this:

```
cookieService.set(response,"cookieName", user.id + "_" + passWordHash, 10 * 365 * 24 * 3600)
response.setCookie("cookieName", user.id + "_" + passWordHash, 10 * 365 * 24 * 3600)
```

edit:
I saw in the cookie Settings in Firefox that the path of my cookie is "/login", all other cookies are path "/", I have no idea why but maybe this is the problem. Does somebody know how I can change the path of it?

Comment: are u trying to call this where?! controller?!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
request.getCookie("cookieName")
```

check if the cookie is even in the request?! if it is I would say that something wrong with the cookies plugin!
If is not there, it seems you are not setting right the cookie!

**EDIT**
Also try this:

```
request.cookies.each { println "${it.name} == ${it.value}" }
```

so you can see all cookies you have set!

Comment: I invoke the code in my question in a controller, yes. This line with request returns null too, so you think it´s the plugin? I set the cookie like shown above in my edit. In the settings of fire fox the cookie is displayed correctly so I think I set it propperly

Comment: @dan I edited my replay! try checking all cookies! I am guessing that your might be missing something before your request get your controller!

Comment: @dan try algo the tag <cookie:get name='cookieName' /> in same GSP to check if is there!!

Comment: hmm I get cookies but not the one I set. I tryed a different approach to set the cookie, see in edit. Any ideaas how to solve this?

Comment: response.setCookie seems right to me! question: are u testing it in a right order?! first are you senting the cookies in the response then i try to get it in a new request?!

Comment: I set the cookie, close the browser and then invoke the code which gets the cookie. Hmm, assuming the plugin has a bug, does anybody know a different way to set a cookie?